# How do you sort a list with a comparison function where values for a & b are known ahead of time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a simple interpreter that people can use (among other things) to sort a list via a comparison function (preferably a stable sort). Sorting algorithms that I'm familiar with all seem to require a *variable* number of calls to that comparison function and you don't know **ahead of time** which items will be compared to each other. That won't work because of the nature of what work is done in the interpreted language vs the runtime at what times.

The steps required by the interpreter are:

**Step 1**: Create a list of `a`s to be compared to another list of `b`s, one `a` & `b` at a time. Something like `sort([1, 2, 3])` producing:

```
a = [2, 3]
b = [1, 2]
```

(`2` is compared to `1` and then `3` is compared to `2` in the above example, going index by index.)

**Step 2**: Create two new lists (`before` and `after`) with the same number of items as `a` and `b` to represent the result of the comparison function. The values are any null or non-null value. Something like:

```
before = [2, 3]
after = [null, null]
```

(`2` should come before `1`, representing `1` from `b` as null. The non-null values are preserved, but any non-null value could be in `2`'s place.)

I can impose a limitation that the values in `before` and `after` must be items from the lists `a` and `b`, but I'd prefer not to if I possibly can. I mention it because I'm unsure how I could know where the non-`null` value came from (`a` or `b`). But if the items compared from `a` and `b` are the same but only one is `null` at the end, I have the same problem.

**Step 3**: Use those two lists `before` and `after` to sort the original list. Something like:

```
sort([1, 2, 3], greaterThan) => [3, 2, 1]
// a = [2, 3]
// b = [1, 2]
// before = [2, 3]
// after = [null, null]
```

(If both values are non-`null` or both `null`, it should favor their original order relative to each other, or a "stable" sort.)

In such a trivial example, the items in `a` and `b` are sufficient to sort the list. The Javascript (the language the interpreter is written in) `Array.sort` method will compare them like this:

```
(2, 1)
(3, 2)
```

and be done. But if the order of the original list were `[2, 3, 1]` then it has to do:

```
(3, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
```

(I don't know why or what algorithm they use).

In that example, I would have to provide lists `a` and `b` as `[3, 1, 1, 1]` and `[2, 3, 2, 3]` respectively.

---

How do I get a list for `a` and `b` that will work given any comparison function or order of the original list -- and *then* use the resulting `before` and `after` lists to sort that original list?

Comment: Are you asking about Cycle sort?

Comment: @Neil I may be wrong, but it looks like Cycle Sort uses a variable number of comparisons.

Comment: I think [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis) has bounded number. [Merge-insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort) if you want to optimize the number of compares. I'm not quite sure what you are asking with `a` and `b`. A constant number of comparisons for all cases (of the same size) and stable? Are you asking with constant `a` and `b` pre-calculate a permutation that sorts in `O(n)`?

Comment: I'm having trouble following what the null terms in `after` represent. Can you elaborate on that?